# Hide link but show on hover not working - CSS

Tags: css, visibility

This seems to make perfect sense, but it is not working. I seem to be breaking a rule of some sort. I am trying to have a link show up as transparent (not show up at all) and to show itself on hover. The only constraints I have it that this cannot have a solid color as the background is not solid.

**jsfiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/AmDUH/

**HTML:**

```html
<a href="#">Click here</a>
```

​
**CSS:**

```css
a{
visibility:hidden;
}
a:hover{
visibility:visible;
}
```

​Is there any solution to do this in css? Seems to be straightforward if I could just apply a transparent color, but that's not possible from my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
a{
opacity:0.0;
}
a:hover{
opacity:1.0;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks for the quick response. Just a second faster than @David Thomas

Answer (score 4):

You could use, instead, `opacity`:

```
a{
    opacity: 0;
}
a:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AmDUH/1/).

Answer (score 0):

That's hiding the visibility from the user... Of course you can't hover over because it's "invisible". I would try to do something along these lines:

```
a:link {color:#FFFFFF;}
a:visited {color:#000000;}
a:hover {color:#000000;}
a:active {color:#000000;}
```

Or play with
    opacity:0.0